# VSTS Permission to one branch

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a user who is a stakeholder in VSTS. He needs to be able to access a branch in the project I am working on. So he can work on it then commit to it. I don't want him to see any other projects I have on VSTS. Is this possible? I don't really want  him to be able to access the other branches but it doesn't matter too much - hiding the other projects is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually people with **Stakeholder**  access level could not commit their work on branch.

> Assign Stakeholder access to those users who need to **enter bugs,
>   view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards,** but who don't have a
>   TFS CAL. Stakeholders can also view releases and manage release
>   approvals. Stakeholder access is free.
>
> *Source Link: [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels)*

[image]

See [Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder) for details of features available to stakeholders.

The user should have either **Basic access** or **VS Enterprise** which include **code**  feature.

---

Moreover, it's able to forbid him to see any other projects you have on VSTS. This is another concept called **[Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level)**  in VSTS. Do not add him to any other project team group expect the one he will work on.

You could also be able to deny the **Read** permission for branch/folder level

> ***Read***
>
> Can read the contents of a file or folder. If a user has Read
>   permissions for a folder, the user can see the contents of the folder
>   and the properties of the files in it, even if the user does not have
>   permission to open the files.